# How to install OpenJDK8

Tags: java

I am having a hard time download OpenJDK for Linux (RedHat). I do not see any links to download the latest version of jdk8 on site 
https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/

There is a link for Early Access ( https://jdk.java.net/8/ ) but I am not looking for that release as it clearly states "*Early-access (EA) functionality might never make it into a general-availability (GA) release.*". I would like to download one that is in GA (General Availability).

The archive link does not provide any information for jdk8.
https://jdk.java.net/archive/

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the one that Redhat provides? Which is the preferred way of installation, judging from the [OpenJDK install page](https://openjdk.java.net/install/).

```
yum info java-1.8.0-openjdk

Name        : java-1.8.0-openjdk 
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.8.0.181
Release     : 3.b13.el7_5
Size        : 501 k
From repo   : rhel-7-server-rpms
```

Answering the comments:

Version locking can be achieved with `yum-plugin-versionlock` or rather by providing a local mirror (using [Foreman](https://theforeman.org/) and its ['Content Views'](https://theforeman.org/plugins/katello/3.10/user_guide/content_views/index.html) feature).

Downloading a RPM to a box can be done from a properly registered host with `yumdownloader` (see the `yum-utils` package).

Should you nonetheless be keen on installing your own version, creating a RPM is recommended. Take a look on how the Redhat/CentOS folk [do it](https://git.centos.org/blob/rpms!java-1.8.0-openjdk.git/8ba7a77893175ee1c9573a27fb3d731ca2f43a81/SPECS!java-1.8.0-openjdk.spec) or use one of the other [approaches](https://github.com/puzzle/java-oracle-rpm/blob/master/java-1.7.0-oracle.spec) as inspiration.

Comment: Because I dont control the yum repo and the jdk version will keeping getting updated on the repo. I need to be able to control the jdk version that I install across the enterprise.

Comment: If there is way I can download that rpm to a tar.gz file, I can live with it.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: I used yumdownloader but it simply provides the rpm file. I am looking for a tar.gz of the java binaries.

Comment: @user1074593 Why do you want a tarball of Java instead of a fully supported package from Red Hat? That sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Like I mentioned earlier, if I go with yum the jdk version will keep changing on the servers. Effectively, for a particular application, dev could get one version of jdk , qa could get another and prod a third. I need to keep the jdk version consistent across the enterprise. Its actually more  complicated than this but simplifying it.

Comment: @user1074593 I strongly suggest that you take a look at Foreman. It allows you to do this with pretty much any package.

Comment: @user1074593 If you install this version, you'll remain on this version until you explicitly install another version. I don't know where you got the idea that you would be upgraded without your knowledge, but it doesn't appear to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [openjdk.java.net](https://openjdk.java.net/) is for builds of the OpenJDK provided by Oracle (which is *not* the same as Oracle JDK published under OTN license).

An alternative would be to use another distribution of OpenJDK:

- The free version of [Azul Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulu-linux/)
- [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html) has both HotSpot and OpenJ9
- Or see this blog entry by Stephen Colebourne, which gives links to other distributions: [Time to look beyond Oracle's JDK](https://blog.joda.org/2018/09/time-to-look-beyond-oracles-jdk.html) .